# Electrostatic potential of a dipole in a non-uniform field

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole

There are numerous derivations for the potential energy of a dipole in a uniform field as:
$$
U = - \boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{E}
$$
But does this hold also for **non-uniform** fields? Are there any links to derivation (e.g. is there a Taylor expansion for $\boldsymbol{E}(\boldsymbol{r+\delta \boldsymbol{r}})$ that one could use)? For example, DaniH mentions this in his comments of [The formula of the force exerted on an electric dipole by non-uniform electric field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44475/246795) but I am unsure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general approach would be to model the dipole as a compactly supported charge distribution $\rho(x)$ that integrates to zero (*i.e.* no *net* charge). So if the dipole is "located at" point $y$, then the charge density at the point $x + y$ is $\rho(x)$. (Note that $x$ and $y$ stand for vectors. I omit the arrows for brevity.)

We'll assume that the electric field is also compactly supported. This gives an obvious way to define the zero point of the potential: $U = 0$ when the dipole is far away enough that it's disjoint from the electric field. Let's say the initial position is $y_1$, so $U(y_1) = 0$.

We can now move the dipole toward another point $y_2$ while keeping its orientation fixed. In moving it from $y$ to $y + dy$, the infinitesimal increment of work performed is

$$ dU = - dy \cdot \int \rho(x) E(y + x) \, dx $$

The potential energy at the final position of the origin is therefore

$$ U(y_2) = - \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \int \rho(x) E(y + x) \, dx \cdot dy $$

Note that the integral over $y$ is a line integral (so $dy$ is a vector) while the integral over $x$ is a space integral.

At this point we can approximate $E(y + x) \approx E(y) + x \cdot \nabla E(y)$ as mentioned by DaniH, obtaining

$$ U(y_2) \approx -\int_{y_1}^{y_2} \int \rho(x) E(y) \, dx \cdot dy - \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \int \rho(x) [x \cdot \nabla E(y)] \, dx \cdot dy$$

Having eliminated $x + y$, we can now factor both terms:

$$ U(y_2) \approx -\left[ \int \rho(x) \, dx\right] \left[\int_{y_1}^{y_2} E(y) \, d\ell\right] - \left[ \int x \rho(x) \, dx \right] \cdot \left[\int_{y_1}^{y_2} \nabla E(y) \cdot d\ell\right]$$

We assumed the total charge is zero (*i.e.*, no monopole moment), so the first term vanishes. In the second term, the first factor is just the total dipole moment $p$, and the second factor just integrates to $E(y_2) - E(y_1)$. But we assumed $E(y_1) = 0$, so the final result is just $U(y_2) \approx - p \cdot E(y_2)$.

If we add back in the higher order terms from the Taylor expansion, then in general this formula will not be exact. These higher order terms contribute to the final result terms of the form $-\frac{1}{k!} \int x^k \rho(x) \, dx \cdot \int \nabla^k E(y) \, dy$. In order to justify treating these terms as negligible, you need to know something about the variation in $E$. In a typical scenario, each term will diminish by a factor of about $k L/M$, where $L$ is the length scale over which $E$ varies appreciably, and $M$ is the size of the dipole. You can make this precise but physicists typically leave these details to the mathematicians.

Answer (score 0):

The dipole potential , $\phi= \frac{\bf p\cdot r }{r^3}$  is derived by expanding the integral for $\phi$ in powers of 1/r.  Any further step in the 1/r expansion is neglected. This means that any variation in E beyond the constant term does not enter into the dipole potential. This makes ${\bf E=-\nabla\phi}$ for the dipole field a constant even if $\bf E$ itself varies.